# What was the inspiration for the 'draco vulgaris'?

Tags: dragons, discworld, terry-pratchett, dungeons-and-dragons

Is the [draco vulgaris](https://discworld.fandom.com/wiki/Draco_vulgaris) (first described in [*Guards! Guards!* (1989)](https://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Book:Guards!_Guards!) inspired by the [pseudodragons](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Pseudodragon) found in *Dungeons and Dragons*?

I recently learned about them and find many similarities:

- small winged dragon (around than 2 feet long)
- can be a pet
- (relatively) short lived
- limited ability to communicate

Since D&D has many versions, I face difficulties identifying when pseudodragons were first defined but they [seem to be mentioned in a first version (1977)](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Monster_Manual_1st_edition).

Digging around this topic, I found the [small pet dragon trope](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ShoulderSizedDragon): it seems to be even older?

Does anyone have a Terry Pratchett interview or discussion about this topic?

Comment: @valorum why remove the part about not being able to quote their books?

Comment: @Stormblessed - Because OP is right about their in-world first significant mention

Comment: I don't know about inspiration, but the swamp dragons were clearly meant as a parody of [tiny purse-sized dogs](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MisterMuffykins) bred by/for rich women.  They're small, unhealthy, annoying animals bred from a large, dangerous, practical species, and the wiki link you provided mentions a "*The Show Judges' Guide to Dragons*, by Lady Sybil Ramkin".

Comment: That's not the very first version of Dungeons and Dragons.

Comment: The Pern series/world also has small dragons (fire lizards) although the distinction from the full size version seems to simply be size vs the big differences between *D. nobilis* and *D. vulgaris*.  I do like @ArcanistLupus 's comparison with the little yappy dog breeds...

Comment: @DJClayworth I nuanced it, is it better? Thanks everyone else to fix my post.

Comment: draco vulgaris == common dracon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the notion of small dragons (or dragon-like reptiles) is certainly older than Dungeons & Dragons, I think there is actually a good reason to think that Pratchett was, at least in part, inspired by D&D.  That reason is the name:  *Draco vulgaris*.  The first edition of Advanced Dungeons & Dragons had all the non-unique dragons listed in the *[Monster Manual](https://thetrove.net/Books/Dungeons%20and%20Dragons/AD&D%201st%20Edition/Core/Monster%20Manual%201%20%28Orange%20Spine%29.pdf)* given faux-Latin scientific names.

[image: Draco Causticus Sputem]

These include *Draco Causticus Sputem, Draco Electricus, Draco Impudentus Gallus, Draco Orientalus Sino Dux, Draco Chlorinous Nauseous Respiratorus, and Draco Conflagratio Horriblis*, among others.  Later books identified the Platinum Dragon, Bahamut, as having the Latinate name *Draco Paladin*.  The name *Draco vulgaris* (which is dog Latin for "common dragon") follows this pattern.  Since the made-up dragon names were an innovation of first edition AD&D, I suspect that Pratchett had the D&D dragons in mind as he was writing *Guards! Guards!*

Comment: Many thanks @Buzz ! Another clue of this https://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Dungeons_and_Dragons "It is thought that The Colour of Magic originated from Terry Pratchett's experiences as a Dungeon-Master and some of the things he incorporated in the RPG group he ran - ie, the Luggage originated as somewhere to stash the loot but from which the loot could not necessarily be retrieved, depending on the beast's mood"

Comment: I think that your argument is very weak. Making up scientific names for fictional creatures is [widely practised](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CanisLatinicus), and Pratchett's work contains [many other dog-Latin phrases](https://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Latatian_Phrases).

Comment: ...and that entry in lspace is unreferenced (In fact I've since removed it for being unreferenced).

Comment: @OrangeDog It's even a name that has been used for an actual species (though the Linnean name that was ultimately settled upon was *Draco volans*. https://archive.org/details/booknatureembra01philgoog/page/n22

Comment: *Draco vulgaris* being (not even doggish) Latin for "common dragon", and *Draco volans* being "flying dragon"

Answer (score 14):

I'd be very surprised if D&D Pseudodragons were the initial inspiration for Draco Vulgaris. As [the TV Tropes page](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ShoulderSizedDragon) says, small pet dragons predate them in a significant way. The tropes page guesses that the Trope maker (i.e. work that popularized it) was [Dragonquest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonquest) by [Anne McCaffrey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anne_McCaffrey), a 1970 work, but the also appear in [A Wizard of Earthsea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wizard_of_Earthsea) by [Ursula Le Guin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ursula_K._Le_Guin). Mr Pratchett was clearly aware of *Dragonquest* because he parodied the entire *Dragonriders of Pern* series in *The Colour of Magic* (thanks Sarriesfan for reminding me). It hard to imagine that given those two huge influences Mr Pratchett would give main credit for the inspiration to a fairly obscure D&D monster. Of course, as with most literary inspirations, it's likely that the creatures didn't derive from a single source.

Comment: Interesting; I'd assumed it was the *Harper Hall* series; I'd completely forgotten that the fire-lizards showed up in the original series.

Comment: The Wyrmberg section of The Colour of Magic is a parody of the Pern books Sir Terry was clearly familiar with the stories. Lessa becomes Liessa for example.